# Align absolute positioned child to a over-hidden relative parent

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div id="main_wrapper" style="width: 80vw; overflow: hidden;">
     <div id="inner_wrapper" style="position: relative;">
         <div id="red" style="background-color: red;width: 20vw;height: 100px;position: absolute;left: 80vw;"></div> 

         <div id="blue" style="background-color:blue; height:100px; margin: 0px 1% 0px 1%;"></div> 
     </div> 
 </div>
```

Here is the js-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omriman12/msrpwnym/1/

Basically the `main_wrapper` over-hidden's `inner_wrapper`, and what i want to do is to align `red` to the right of `blue` element.

My problem is that `red` gets over-hidden when i use relative.

**I must keep it relative! This is part of the question, dont change the structure!**

Here is what i am actually[image] trying to create:

Comment: I have no idea what "hoverhidden" or "over-hidden" means

Comment: so you want the red to be over the right of the blue, right?

Comment: @Thinker yes, it must flow as absolute and the inner_wrapper i want to relative to keep then align in y-axis.

Comment: Might we ask **why** the overflow must be hidden?

Comment: That part of the question, in the actual program its a table and the blue is like a popup to the right of the table row

Comment: You guys can look at the picture i added, that the final result i want to accomplish, its a list with a rightside popup

Comment: Then I'd suggest that this is not possible. You many have to re-think your methodology.

Comment: @Paulie_D how would you suggest to build the structure if not like that, take in mind the scroll bar. I need to know the x,y of the row when clicked

Comment: @omriman12 Is the image you added the result you want? Could you tell me what the actual issue you are facing and the result you need are if the image is right the issue presentation.

Comment: @Anson imagin a table like in the picture, with a scroll bar. When a button on the row is clicked a popup will be shown floating in the right side of that row, thats it

Comment: @omriman12 Let me do clarify. The popup you said is the window which is with the cursor, right?

Comment: Then you'll probably need javascript to pop it out from somewhere else. AFAIK, once you apply `overflow:hidden` that's it,,,no takebacks. Also, if you are using a table then **that** is the structure you should be showing us.

Comment: @Paulie_D its not a table as is, its a div rows.. I found some kind of solution, i will update later, still not working well with the scroll

Comment: ..but you said it **is** a table --> *" in the actual program its a table"*

Comment: @Paulie_D its rows.. well i solved the problem using JS as you said, i removed the position:relative, meaning the "red" will float aligned on the right of the blue, for the y axix i calculated the "scroll offset" and fixed to align

Comment: @omriman12 Could you share the solution to us?

Comment: @Anson its basically removing the relative in the inner_wrapper, and using javascript-> var marginTop = $('#main_wrapper').scrollTop(); to get the scrolled pixels

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The problem is that you set `#main_wrapper` to `width: 80vw` and `overflow-x: hidden`. That caused any child will be hidden if those children are wider than **80vw**. You have to wide `#main_wrapper` to **100vw** and set the width `#inner_wrapper` with **80vw** for displaying child of `#main_wrapper`.

By the way, you need to dynamically resize the width of `#main_wrapper` when each row is clicked as below snippet.

```js
$('.row').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $('#main_wrapper').width('100vw');
  } else {
    $('#main_wrapper').width('80vw');
  }
});
```

```css
#main_wrapper{
  width: 80vw;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

#inner_wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
}

#blue{
  background-color:blue; 
  height:100px; 
  margin: 0px 1% 0px 1%;
}

#red{
  background-color: red;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 80vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_wrapper">
  <div id="inner_wrapper" class="row">
    <div id="red" ></div> 
    <div id="blue"></div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: thx for the effort, thats not what i am looking for, the red should not be within the scroll, thats not the question description. it should be as the pic - floating on the right, the scroll should be on the left side of "red"

Comment: Is the scroll-y for scrolling the rows in `#main_wrapper`?